# App rejected due to file selection

Tags: ios, objective-c

Apple rejects my app and I got this response from the developers.

> Guideline 2.5.15 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> We noticed that your app enables users to view and select files, but it still does not include functionality to allow users to view or select items from the Files app and the user's iCloud documents, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please revise your app to allow users to view and select items from the Files app and the user's iCloud documents.

Comment: Please edit headline of this question, as it's not intuitive of what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a setting to allow other apps to edit files like it [says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider?language=objc):

> To give other apps access to the files in your Documents directory,
>   just set the proper keys in your app's Info.plist file. You can either
>   set the UISupportsDocumentBrowser key (for document browser-based
>   apps), or set both the UIFileSharingEnabled and
>   LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace keys.